# Inconsistent Return Type

Tags: python

Class `Human` inherits from Python built-in 'dict' class. As an argument it expects a dictionary. `.getCars()` method returns a value stored in "car" or "cars" dictionary key. For the key "car" the return value is a string. For the key "cars" the value is a list of strings. So `.getCars()` method  will be returning two types of values: string or list.
Needless to say dealing with `getCars()` method will become tedious really fast. I would have to keep checking what it is returning this time: list or string... That would result to numerous if/else statements later on. My question : What design/approach to take in a situation like this? Should I enforce to the same type of return value (let's say regardless if there is only car or many - `.getCars()` always returns a list). While this approach would result to a consistent return value-type it may produce problems later. Since with a single car packed into a list variable I would have to do `if returned_list: real_return_value=returned_list[0]` which is kind of redundant too.

```
class Human(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Human, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def getCars(self):
        if 'cars' in self: return self.get('cars')
        elif 'car' in self: return self.get('car')

cars={'cars':['BMW','Porsche','Mercedes-Benz']}
car={'car':'Geo Metro'}

wealthy=Human(cars)
froogle=Human(car)

print wealthy.getCars()
print froogle.getCars()
```

Comment: Why is any of this happening? Why does `Human` inherit from `dict`? Why does it accept either `car` or `cars` to specify its cars? Can you normalize it so that it will always have a list of cars, even if the input has a single car?

Comment: The reason Human inherits from dictionary is because incoming arguments for this class are always dictionary with endless database generated keys (with a lot of them nested). Some of the database delivered dictionary keys will be marked as "car" some "cars". "Car" will be storing a string. "Cars" a list of strings. But both keys will be describing the same things: cars.... only the quantity will be different: a single or many. I am trying to figure out a way to "normalize" and minimize the incoming complexity to something simpler workable managable.

Comment: I can normalize the return of `getCars()` method to a list even if it returns a single value. BUT. I before I do it I would like to make sure there is no other way to do it with more elegance. Because normalizing or enforcing a return value to a specific data type is kind of "enforced".

Comment: That's not a reason to inherit from `dict`. That's possibly a reason to have a dict instance variable, or to process the incoming dict to extract data into instance variables.

Comment: I don't get your point.

Comment: I think her/his point is that your design is going to cause problem later. For example, you can still access elements using [], which completely bypasses getCars(). And, you can use it to both set and retrieve the contents of 'car' and 'cars'. This means that by standard means (a human is a dict, and dicts support []), code can completely mess with your design. Hence also the suggestion to perhaps use a dict to store properties but not to derive from it. Further, stay with getCars() and handle that the returned set can contain 0 to N elements, as a generalization of plural, singular and none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest normalizing the return type in addition to normalizing the key you use to look up the data. That is, always return a list of cars, even if there's only one under the key `"car"`. I don't think there is any more elegant solution:

```
def getCars(self):
    if "cars" in self:
        return self["cars"]
    elif "car" in self:
        return [self["car"]]  # build a list for the single car!
    else:
        return []  # return an empty list if neither key exists
```

An alternative to returning an empty list if no cars exist for a person might be to raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks! I want to make sure that we realize that I am asking not on how to normalize but rather a question is "SHOULD I normalize"... and is it a common practice in programming to normalize the return data type to a single type. Or may be it is OK (or opposite a big "No No") to return different value types from a single function/method?

Comment: I think it's much easier to use a single return type (e.g. a `list`) and then to have your code key off of the value (e.g the `len()` of the list) rather than returning different either a single item or a list of items. In many situations you may be able to treat all lists the same, even if some have many items and others only one (or even zero). For instance, if you loop over the cars, it shouldn't matter how many of them there.

Comment: consistent interfaces in all circumstances are easier to develop against (fewer "special cases"), and much easier to test. +1 for this answer and comment